# Converting Tensor of shape (?,100,100,1) to numpy array error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to convert a tensor of shape `(?,100,100,1)` to a numpy array with `.eval()`. But I keep getting an error. I think that it has no way to use the information contained in the first dimension to convert it. I tried using `clear_session()`, but it doesn't work.

Perhaps i could feed the value 1 into that position. How would i do it?

I am runing the call method in a custom layer

```
def call(self,x):
     input_tensor=x

     with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
        x_unpacked = input_tensor.eval()
      .......
```

What i would like to do is have a different rule for processing each training example in the custom layer, that depends on the values in that training examples array. So i tried to evaluate x at each call, which may not be what its doing.

Non the less it would be good to know how to get the value of each training example just before the layer processes it so that i can choose how to process it in the rest of the call statement.

the error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1367, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1352, in _run_fn
target_list, run_metadata)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1445, in _call_tf_sessionrun
run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,10 0,100,1]
[[{{node input_1}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "finalvideo_2.py", line 630, in
text()
File "finalvideo_2.py", line 498, in text
kikiE(EX_dat,EY_dat)
File "finalvideo_2.py", line 338, in kikiE
x = MyLayer()(input_tensor)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 73, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 489, in call
output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
File "finalvideo_2.py", line 108, in call
self.W = topology(x, self.W2)
File "finalvideo_2.py", line 128, in topology
x_unpacked = input_tensor.eval()
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 790, in eval
return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 5312, in _eval_using_default_session
return session.run(tensors, feed_dict) File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 960, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1183, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1361, in _do_run
run_metadata)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1386, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,10 0,100,1]
[[node input_1 (defined at /home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:676) ]]

Original stack trace for 'input_1':
File "finalvideo_2.py", line 630, in
text()
File "finalvideo_2.py", line 498, in text
kikiE(EX_dat,EY_dat)
File "finalvideo_2.py", line 333, in kikiE
input_tensor = Input(shape=X_D[0].shape)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 178, in Input
input_tensor=tensor)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 87, in init
name=self.name)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 73, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 676, in placeholder
shape=shape, ndim=ndim, dtype=dtype, sparse=sparse, name=name)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 1054, in placeholder
x = array_ops.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2718, in placeholder
return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6032, in placeholder
"Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 742, in _apply_op_helper
attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 595, in _create_op_internal
compute_device)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3322, in _create_op_internal
op_def=op_def)
File "/home/usergpu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1756, in init
self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Comment: You need to provide a _complete_ example. What is `input_tensor`? If it's not properly defined (e.g. a placeholder), it cannot be evaluated without feeding a value.

Comment: Well.... it's a "placeholder", it doesn't "contain" anything. You can't eval something that is empty. The answer is: there is nothing inside.

Comment: Would a solution be to have a ```for x in range(len(dataset)): model.train_on_batch(dataset[x-1:x,:,:,:],labels[x-1:x])``` and then have x as a global variable in the call method and then fill the placeholde with values from dataset[x-1:x,:,:,:]?